# TCP/IP optimization in XP and higher?

Tags: tcpip

I heard TCP/IP settings were just optimized for 10/100 LAN. Would TCP/IP optimization for broadband like cable make any difference to performance?

Comment: I don't have enough time to answer right now, but XP needs to be set by hand while vista and seven do things automatically. [This](http://www.dslreports.com/tweaks) site can give some information on what needs to be done to XP.

Comment: I have never had a problem with XP SP2 or higher on any broadband connection, I currently have Fios and there are no speed issues. Tweak at your own risk.

Comment: Yeah I have no performance issue in general. Just wondering if I can get more of a (small) performance boost especially from XP. I figured Vista and win7 was modern enough that MS will have TCP/IP settings more dynamic to change to any particular type of network.